# Ajax submit redirects to new page (should not)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't figure out why I'm not able to properly do the ajax magic with this code. It just redirects to a new page as the server handle the request. I tried put a `console.log("test");` in the jquery function, but it's never called. So I'm guessing the form submit never go through my ajax but directly to the server.

```
$("#startTest").submit(function(e)
            {
                console.log("test"); //This is never called
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax(
                {
                    url : 'handler',
                    type: "POST",
                    data : $(this).serialize(),
                    success:function(data) 
                    {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function() 
                    {
                        alert("failure"); 
                    }
                });
            });


<form id="startTest" method="POST" action="handler">
    <input type="hidden" name="answer" value="startTest">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="Navn" id="navn" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start test">
</form>
```

Comment: Created a JSFiddle out of it and it fires up just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/r7cwv716/ Are you having any errors in your console?

Comment: I've got no errors in the console :l

Answer (score 0):

Empty your form action. If your form has an action then when you submit your script follows that action. But you want to achieve that process via ajax so you don't fill action tag.Something like this

```
<form id="startTest" method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="answer" value="startTest">
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="Navn" id="navn" autocomplete="off"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start test">
```

Comment: That did not do it. It'll just call another ajax function I've got which is triggered by a click function.

Comment: that fiddle example show that you console.log works fine, other than that i don't know what may cause this situation? maybe your handler url has something that redirects page?